# IPython and __doc__

Tags: python-2.7, ipython

I am using IPython, which is downloaded from "Enthought Python Distribution"

Under IPython / Python 2.7.3, when I type `help(__doc__)`, the result is:

```
In  [26]: help(__doc__)
no Python documentation found for 'Automatically created module for IPython interactive environment'
```

What is the meaning of this result? IPython does not support?

Thanks!

Comment: `__doc__` is a string. Those are its contents.

Comment: The question is what are you trying to do ? (also usually in IPython you can get help by doing `object?`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Blender says, `__doc__` is just a string, and is usually the help string for a given function or module. For example,

```
In [1]: numpy.__doc__
Out[1]: '\nNumPy\n=====\n\nProvides\n  1. An array object of arbitrary homogeneous items\n  2. Fast mathematical operations over arrays\n ...
```

is the help string for the `numpy` module. Calling `help()` on `numpy` essentially just prints out a nicely formatted version of this string:

```
Help on package numpy:

NAME
    numpy

FILE
    /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py

DESCRIPTION
    NumPy
    =====

    Provides
      1. An array object of arbitrary homogeneous items
      2. Fast mathematical operations over arrays
      ...
```

In IPython, the string `__doc__` is just:

```
In [3]: __doc__
Out[3]: 'Automatically created module for IPython interactive environment'
```

Calling `help(__doc__)` then looks for `__doc__.__doc__`, which doesn't exist.